# Vacuum cleaner charged with murder

Tags: story-identification

This should be easy. I have the book around somewhere, but I can't remember the title or author. A scientist tries to upload his mind into an AI-equipped vacuum cleaner, but during the process the vacuum cleaner panics and disconnects, killing the scientist. Authorities charge the vacuum cleaner with murder and a lawyer spends most of the story trying to work up a defense. He is so preoccupied he ignores the condition of his dying wife.

Comment: +1 just for a title that made me simultaneously snort and doubt my eyesight.

Comment: Believe it or not, until I clicked in, I had a different story in mind... different plotline overall, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess the person in charge of removing space debris from earth orbit could be called a vacuum cleaner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [The Modular Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Modular_Man) by Roger MacBride Allen.

Per wikipedia:

> The novel concerns the issue of personhood and what it takes to be
>   considered a member of the moral universe. **There are three main
>   characters: Herbert the vacuum cleaner, who is modified by his owner,
>   David Bailey, a scientist who specializes in figuring out how to
>   "mindload".** Mindloading is the act of a human downloading their mind
>   into a machine. A successful mindload entails the death of the human.
>   It is a way for humans to become immortal, if only in the form of
>   vacuum cleaner.
>
> **The book begins with the arrest of Herbert, the vacuum cleaner, for
>   David's murder.** David's wife, Suzanne Jantille, is a trial attorney
>   who is a quadriplegic as a result of a car crash that also paralyzed
>   her husband. She lives through a "Remote person" who has all human
>   senses except for the ability to feel by touch. She can guide the
>   remote person through a helmet attached to her "bio body" and
>   retrieves all "video and audio" signals through the remote. She can
>   function as a whole human being, but the outside world notices that
>   she is a remote — and does not approve.